# Change the value in the user join date field

Tags: users

I am building a Drupal 7 site.

User can register in my site using Hybridauth or regular registration form.

I want to change the value in the joined date field.
Meaning change the date a user joined the site.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Old users:  update the users table in your database.  It will be far more efficient.

New users:  https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7     I don't think the date/time are saved in that form, so what you could do is find the UID and update the table using a sql query after the save is done.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How can I update the database table? through the phpmyadmin UI? can you please guide me a little?

Comment: yep! phpmyadmin would work. "update users set created = 'timestampgoeshere'"

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement  [hook_user_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7) like

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) { 
    // your condition goes here
    //$edit['created'] =  REQUEST_TIME - mt_rand(0, 100000);
    $edit['created'] = 1364094210; //timestamp that you want to assign
}
```

If you want to update some specific user joining date
Use

```
// load user object
$existingUser = user_load('USERID');
// update some user property
$existingUser->created = 'TIMESTAMP';
// save existing user
user_save((object) array('uid' => $existingUser->uid), (array) $existingUser);
```